# Why does require("the-module") from a file in another directory fail?

Tags: node.js, npm

When I did `node myfile.js` I got an error that a module was not found. I checked `module.paths` like this:

```
$ node
> module.paths
```

The path where the module is installed showed up and I could require the module:

```
$ node
> require("the-module")
```

So I added `console.log(module.paths)` to `myfile.js` to see if `module.paths` was the same. It was not.

What is going on?

---

EDIT:
It was a bit more complicated.

The `module.paths` are different, but that does not seem to be the problem. The path where `the-module` is installed is in the list.

When I add `require("the-module")` in `myfile.js` it works as expected. However I do `require("c:/path-to/other-file.js")` and from there I do another `require("the-module")`. This require fails.

---

EDIT 2:
`module.paths` is `other-file.js` is different. Why? (And the path where `the-module` is installed is not in this list.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see all the rules for how `require()` loads files when you don't specify a full path [here](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_all_together).

When you specific only a filename, as in `require("the-module")`, node.js looks in the node_modules sub-directory below the directory that the current module you are calling `require()` from was loaded.  It is done this way so that a module can have its own set of dependencies and can load them relative to it's own directory without regard from where it is in the file system.

So, if the module you are calling `require()` from was in `c:\myprojects\team\module1` and from within a file in that directory, you call `require("the-module")`, then node.js will look in `c:\myprojects\team\module1\node_modules` to find `the-module.js`.

Similarly, any path that starts with `./` is relative to that same directory, but allows you to reference files in the same directory itself.

node.js does not dynamically add paths to a list of search paths.  It sounds like you have an expectation that as you access various  directories they are somehow automatically added to a search path.  That's now how it works.   The rules for where `require()` looks for relative paths are all spelled out [here](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_all_together).

Also, keep in mind that there is not just one `module` variable across all of node.js.  There's a different one in each file that you load in node.js so `module.paths` very well may be different in each one.  In reality, most node.js developers never use `module.paths` in any way.  If you just follow the rules for how relative paths work for `require()`, you will get what you expect and need.